# Compare two files column values using awk

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Here is the content of two files :

```
Judi # cat File1  
judi /export/home 76  
judi /usr 83  

judi # cat File2  
judi /export/home 79  
judi /usr 82
```

If column 3 of `File2` is greater that column 3 of `File1`, then print `File2`'s lines

judi /export/home 79

Comment: do you mean for each line? can you complete your example in order to make your question clearer? thx

Comment: Are the rows always in the same order?  If they're not does the script need to find the corresponding row in the other file or should it just compare the same numbered row?

Comment: the rows will not be in same order, The predefined value will be available in File1, the current status will be captured in File2, if COLUMN3 of File2 is greater than COLUMN3 of File1, then print File2's lines @David King

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}$3>a[$1$2]&&a[$1$2]{print $0}' file1 file2
```

First `file1` is read and array `a` filled with third column, indexed with 1st and 2nd column. Later on 3rd value of `file2` is compared with `a` and if is larger then the whole line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS='
'
for line in $(cat file1); do
  path=$(echo $line|cut -d' ' -f2)
  value1=$(echo $line|cut -d' ' -f3)
  value2=$(grep " $path " file2|cut -d' ' -f3)

  if [[ "$(echo \"$value2>$value1\"|bc)" == "1" ]]; then
    grep " $path " file2;
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @jimmij, this one liner works for me awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}$3>a[$1$2]&&a[$1$2]{print $0}' file1 file2

Answer (score 0):

For the case when the rows *are* in the same order, there is a much cleaner solution using `paste` to combine the files before processing.  The command `paste file1 file2` will merge the corresponding lines of `file1` and `file2`, like so:

```
$ cat file1
judi /export/home 76
judi /usr 83
$ cat file2
judi /export/home 79
judi /usr 82
$ paste file1 file2
judi /export/home 76    judi /export/home 79
judi /usr 83    judi /usr 82
```

You can then use this in a pipeline to `awk` like so:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '$6 > $3 {print $4, $5, $6}'
judi /export/home 79
```

Of course, this won't work properly if the rows aren't in the same order (as in your case), but it does answer the title question: "Compare two files column values using awk".